# if convert project to Automatic Reference Counting(ARC), Is it still support on iOS 3.X, 4.X?

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting

i not sure about convert project to Automatic Reference Counting(ARC).
it still support on iOS 4.X or lower ?

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can gather yes - ARC is done by the compiler and should be thought of as a wizard or helper that checks all of your code and inserts the correct retain and release statements for you.

This will therefore be compatible with older iOS runtimes.

Edit:

IT will support 4.x but not 3.x

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's supported by 4.x, but not earlier.

Comment: ARC uses a compatibility library for iOS versions older than 5.0, and requires the modern runtime present in 4.0.  Therefore, you can target back to 4.0, but not 3.x.

Comment: Most of ARC is supported on iOS4, but not the weak attribute on properties.

Answer (score 5):

It will support iOS 4 but **not** iOS 3.

Still, there's no full support for iOS 4 since weak references only work on iOS 5. Quoting the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html) directly from Apple:

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit
>   applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not
>   supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.