# iphone automatic reference counting for iOS 4.3 version

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am going to write app for iphone 4.X and I have to implement it quickly.I read that   automatic reference counting(ARC) manages the memory and consequently it will save my time.I have read [this](http://hackerne.ws/item?id=3044685) article, in which saying that ARC also works for iOS 4.3. 
Have someone such practice and how much it will be efficiently manage my application memory?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [if convert project to Automatic Reference Counting(ARC), Is it still support on iOS 3.X, 4.X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421753/if-convert-project-to-automatic-reference-countingarc-is-it-still-support-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flanfl's answer is incorrect.

iOS 4 *does* support [ARC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting), but without support for automatic weak reference zeroing. Also known as "ARClite".

See Apple's document on "[Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html)".

- ARC requires Xcode 4.2 or later.
- ARC deploys back to iOS 4.

See this other question on StackOverflow.com:
[Is ARC really supported in iOS 4? The iOS 4.2 SDK is missing ARC-related symbols at linking time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747783/is-arc-really-supported-in-ios-4-the-ios-4-2-sdk-is-missing-arc-related-symbols)

By the way, **version 4.2.1** is the latest version of iOS 4 that runs on all devices that cannot support iOS 5 & 6. Specifically, on the iPhone 3G and iPod touch (2G) version 4.2.1 is the highest supported OS. That is according to my reading of this Wikipedia page, [List of iOS Devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices).

As to the original question: Yes, ARC eliminates the need for calls to *retain* and *release* in most common apps. That makes managing memory much easier for you. Apple strongly recommends ARC for both new projects and for older projects that can be refactored appropriately.

In Apple's iOS [developer web site](https://developer.apple.com), see documents and WWDC videos explaining the details of ARC and how use it in your apps. For example, [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

In iOS 4, in particular, you should set to nil all *outlet* references in your class' *dealloc* method.

Answer (score 0):

If you look around on the Internet it is said that ARC is for iOS 5 http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/

However, if you use ARC in your project, the application will work for iOS 4 and 5.

Here a discussion about ARC:
[Some questions about Automatic Reference Counting in iOS5 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368600/some-questions-about-automatic-reference-counting-in-ios5-sdk)